# how to create thumbnails image in android

Tags: android

I want to create thumbnail image from its original image in coding for android

Answer (score 1):

What's your source data? Do you have a Bitmap? Or a file?
If you have a file, the easiest way would be to scale it as you load it, i.e. pass in a BitmapFactory.Options`enter code here` object and set the inSampleSize to a number that will create the size that you want. Alternatively, you can just create the Bitmap and scale it using `Canvas.drawBitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails`